# difference between angular 1.5 components and modules

Tags: angularjs, module, components

In getting used to module patterns and components I am trying to figure a better way to style an angular app.  A question that I cannot explain to myself fully is...

What is the difference between a component and a module in angular js?

Components have life cycles.  With the exception of children they seemingly stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

From the Angular documentation:
A Module is "a container for the different parts of your app – controllers, services, filters, directives, etc."

A Component is "a special kind of directive that uses a simpler configuration which is suitable for a component-based application structure."
Components are supported from Angular 1.5 on and are provided as a way to bridge the gap between the Angular 1 approach and the Angular 2 approach.

You can think of the Module as the library that holds all of your components. For example, imagine you have a set of components for displaying information about restaurants. You may have a location component, details component, menu component, etc. You would put all of these components in your Restaurant Module. Then users could import your Restaurant Module and have access to all the cool Restaurant components.

When I discovered Components I actually had trouble differentiating them from Directives. Although, the Angular docs do provide a good comparison table here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component